# how to extract text outside tags xml

Tags: xml, text, xpath, tags, extract

I want to extract text outside tags. For example,

```
<body>
    This is an exmaple
    <p>
        blablabla
    </p>
    <references>
        refer 1
        refer 2
    </references>
</body>
```

I want to get the text "This is an example" only without text in other tags (p or reference). I tried several methods but does not work. Any1 can help? Big thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must think a text inside a tag like a node. A text node is retrieved using the test node `text()`. Example. Given:

```
<body>
    This is an exmaple
    <p>
    blablabla
    <\p>
    <references>
        refer 1
        refer 2
    <\references>
    another example
<\body>
```

XPath:

```
"/body/text()"
```

Will retrieve all children text nodes of `body`, like "This is an exmaple" and "another example", while:

```
"/body/text()[1]"
```

will retrieve only the first one, "This is an exmaple". If you want all the descendant text nodes you can use:

```
"/body//text()"
```

or, you want all the text nodes inside first p:

```
"/body/p[1]//text()"
```

Comment: can this be done by c# xmldocument or xmlreader? I am trying to read the text and write the text to another xml for indexing.

Comment: Sure you can need first to use the XPath on the xmldocument with some method like SelectNodes or SelectSingleNode (don't use that since one year at least).

Answer (score 2):

Use this XPath: `/body/text()`. It will select `This is an exmaple`.