# Get information from between two tags in Java HtmlUnit

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

```
<span>
<a></a>
Hello
<div>A very lot of unnecessary text</div>
</span>
```

So I want to extract the "Hello" from the web page. I can select the span via XPath, but if I call .getTextContent() on it I also get what's in the div, but I want this unnecessary text not to be extracted. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide a sample code with your attempt so far.

Comment: String s = page.getElementsByTagName("span").get(0).getTextContent();

Comment: I don't know how to get the text between the anchor and the div

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use xpath to get the text directly as shown in the answer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871273/how-to-extract-text-outside-tags-xml)